# How can I get video thumbnail of youtube and vimeo embed code using php?

Tags: php, wordpress, video, youtube, embed

I have a *WordPress* site in which I am inserting video embed code in the post editor. In the front end I need to show the video Thumbnail on click on them it will show the video in lightbox.

The requirement is that, I need to show the video thumbnail of the videos I have given in the editor.

I will use YouTube and vimeo embed code and if it is other video then I will show post thumbnail, or a default image.

I will use one video embed code per posts.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried looking at the youtube/video apis to get the thumbnail?

Comment: "How to get thumbnail of YouTube video link using YouTube API?" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-to-get-thumbnail-of-youtube-video-link-using-youtube-api

Answer (score 9):

Using [Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol)

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/VIDEO_ID/#.jpg
where,
VIDEO_ID = bQVoAWSP7k4
# = 1,2, or 3
```

Using [Vimeo API](http://developer.vimeo.com/apis/simple)

```
Making Video Request

http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/video_id.output

where, 
video_id :  The ID of the video you want information for.
output  :  Specify the output type. It currently offer JSON, PHP, and XML formats.
```

php code for vimeo:

```
$imgid = 6825415;
$image = unserialize(file_get_contents("http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/$imgid.php"));
echo $image[0]['thumbnail_medium'];
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. But I need to know how can I distinguish between vimeo and youtube video and get the thumbnail of that video

Comment: The # can also (and probably should) be `default`, 1, 2 and 3 being automatically generated and default being choosen by the maker of the video

Answer (score 5):

Thumbnails you can load from video url.

VIDEO URL

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xzf0rvQa4Mc
```

THUMBNAIL URL

```
http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/Xzf0rvQa4Mc/default.jpg

http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/Xzf0rvQa4Mc/default.jpg

http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/Xzf0rvQa4Mc/default.jpg

http://i4.ytimg.com/vi/Xzf0rvQa4Mc/default.jpg
```

It takes some time to replicate images to all thumbnails urls (maybe servers) for new videos.

If there is no thumbnail, it returns image with camera (exactly 893 bytes length).

EXAMPLE

```
    http://i4.ytimg.com/vi/Xzf0rvQa4Md/default.jpg
```

**if you want to get yout tube video id like this**

better with this

```
regexp (youtube\.com\/(watch\?v=)?(v\/)?([\w\-]+))
```

it can handle both urls `(with /v/ and with watch?v=)`

```
preg_match('/youtube\.com\/v\/([\w\-]+)/', $code, $match);

echo $match[3];
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. But I need to know how can I distinguish between vimeo and youtube video and get the thumbnail of that video

Comment: you see this url http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xzf0rvQa4Mc last query string is Xzf0rvQa4Mc id i have check in url regexp (youtube\.com\/(watch\?v=)?(v\/)?([\w\-]+)) and get id this code preg_match('/youtube\.com\/v\/([\w\-]+)/', $code, $match); and set id in this url http://i.ytimg.com/vi/8vZyIiXp4kg/default.jpg

echo $match[3];

Comment: not necessary 1 or 2 or 3  you use in after i (http://i) in url  see this url http://i.ytimg.com/vi/8vZyIiXp4kg/default.jpg

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to use thumbnail through pure js/jquery no api, you can use this tool to capture a frame from the video and voila!

> http://video.depone.eu/

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/video-thumbnails/) which simplifies the process of automatically displaying video thumbnails in your WordPress template.